Suppose $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ with prime index $p$, does this implies that $H$ contains $G^p$?
The power subgroup is defined as $G^p =\left\{g^p \mid g \in G\right\}$.
Question: If $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ with prime index $p$, does this imply that $H$ contains $G^p$?
This statement is true for finitely generated abelian groups by the classification. I was wondering if this is true in general?

Note that in general ${g^p\mid g\in G}$ is not actually a subgroup, and is not denoted by $G^p$. Rather, $G^p$ is defined to be the subgroup generated by the set ${g^p\mid g\in G}$; that is, $G^p = \langle g^p\mid g\in G\rangle$. The set ${g^p\mid g\in G}$ is sometimes denoted $G^{{p}}$.

Thanks @ArturoMagidin, I thought if $G$ is abelian, then $G^p =\left{g^p \mid g \in G\right}$ is a subgroup. What would go wrong in the non-abelian case?

If $G$ is abelian (and more generally, if $G$ is a regular nillpotent group), then $G^p=G^{{p}}$. What goes wrong is that in a general group, the product of two $p$-powers need not be a $p$-power. For instance, in $G=S_3$, $p=3$, the product of the cubes $(12)^3 = (12)$ and $(13)^3 = (13)$ is $(132)$, which is not a cube in $G$.

Note also that the example shows that the normality of $H$ cannot be omitted, since ${e,(12)}$ has index $3$ in $G$, but does not contain all cubes, let alone the subgroup generated by the cubes (which is all of $G$).

Yeah, this is true. Indeed, if you take the quotient $G/H\cong \mathbb Z_p$, then the class of $g^p$ is
$$[g^p]=[g]^p=1_{G/H} \implies g^p\in H.
$$
Here I am using that given a finite group $T$ and an element $t$, then $t^{\vert T\vert}=1_T$.
